# .trace file xcode instruments

Tags: xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am unable to open the .trace file which is the output of a test script run in Xcode-instruments.
When I try to open it, it says Unable to open the file.

Please suggest if there is a way to open it

Answer (score 0):

From Finder, get context menu on file, select "Show Package Contents".  From a command-line shell, just navigate to the file as if it were a directory.

Comment: doesn't instruments open the file?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that there is a second .trace folder inside the top-level .trace folder, and they share the same name. If you drag the second one out, then Instruments will have no problem opening the second one.

I tested this with Xcode4.6 (Instruments 4.5).